# how to print the data which receive from this query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to print the data which i receive from the app.get('/:id',function(){}) but it print nothing on console.
help me to solve this.
below is my "index.js" page code of that part.
I use mongo database to store data.

```js
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;  
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';  



app.get('/:id',function(req,res,next){
 MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
  if(err)return next(err);
  var dbo=db.db("student");
  var id = req.params.id;
 dbo.collection("knit").findOne({_id:ObjectId(id)},function(err,res,body){
  if(err)throw err;
  console.log(body);
 });
 });
});
```

Comment: Try changing your find query like ```dbo.collection("knit").findOne({_id:ObjectId(id)},function(err,body)```

Comment: it's working. Thanks Mr. Mohammed Amir Ansari.

Comment: Glad it helps... happy coding :)